# XAMPP installation: xampp.users and .htaccess files magically show up after Windows 7 system reboot

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

I've just installed XAMPP on my Windows 7 system. I've shut down the system
and restarted, ran XAMPP as administrator and started Apache. I then tried
to access localhost and got the following message:

> A username and password are being requested by `http://localhost`. The site says: "xampp user"

I find this strange since I never installed an xampp user in xampp, not even sure from
where this can be done.

I then found the following files on the system:

`C:\xampp\security\xampp.users` contains the following:

```
secret:$apr1$XmfmmicE$PG0/7jOjQmA9bu9G6A2w0
```

`C:\xampp\security\htdocs` and `C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp` both contain the following:

```
AuthName "xampp user"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "C:\xampp\security\xampp.users"
require valid-use
```

How did these files end up on my system if I never configured an xampp user.

Also, how can I somehow get rid of this configuration and return to what things
were like before this folder appeared? Is it possible some malicious attacker
somehow altered these files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some default thing that got installed, or perhaps something that you inadvertently turned on when you installed XAMPP. It's not looking for "xampp user", the authentication realm is simply named "xampp user" (given by the `AuthName` directive. The username that it actually wants according to the `xampp.users` is "secret". No idea what the password is as it's hashed.

To turn this off, simply remove this line:

```
require valid-use
```

or comment it out (using a `#` at the start of the line).

Comment: I noticed on the XAMPP control panel it is possible to set the XAMPP directory protection (.htaccess) from http:// localhost/security/index.php , however I do not recall setting this manually, I only recall setting the MySQL root password on this page. Is it possible that someone hacked into my system and changed it via this panel? When this happened to me I was in a classroom with other students in the room behind the same firewall. Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, I just changed these files by adding a .bak extension and the problem went away.

Comment: However I would like to determine whether some intruder was able to change these files via the XAMPP control panel. Is my XAMPP control panel visible externally by default? Thanks.

Comment: There has definitely been an intruder on the network. For instance now the root password I set has been removed: The MySQL admin user root has NO password. Will have to look into security matters.

Comment: Anyways I reinstalled and everything is OK. Thank you for explaining about authentication realms and .htacess directives.